# Canon Powershot SX130 IS Lens error

Tags: lens, canon, powershot

So, i was taking some pictures with my camera, and when I wanted to clean it, It said "Lens error, will restart automatically". I did nothing wrong to the camera and to the lens, they were ok, there is no even dust in the lens and the worst thing is that the camera warranty is expired. So, can anyone please help me to fix that problem?

Comment: Have you try to replace the batteries with fresh ones? Also have you consider remove and reinsert (or replace) the time/date battery (as per page 152 of the manual)?

Comment: I don't mean to be harsh, but bear in mind that this camera was released in 2010 and all electronic devices break eventually. Could be anything - a capacitor on an internal circuit - a piece of rubber cracking due to heat - who knows. It's a ~13-year-old consumer camera.